# ASP.NET MVC4 - Multiple models of same type with partial views on the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a single page ASP.NET MVC 4 application which should display charts. Each chart (dotnetHighcharts) is contained in a single partial view with its own model.

Now I want to be able to display multiple charts on a single page, each with its own model, rendered in a partial view.

**My controller looks like this:**

```
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Display(Guid? id)
    {
        var viewModel = PrepareViewModel(id);
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DisplayChart(Guid? id)
    {
        var viewModel = PrepareViewModel(id);
        return PartialView("Partial_ChartView", viewModel);
    }
}
```

**The partial view looks like this:**

```
@model MobileReports.Models.ReportViewModel
@Model.Chart
```

**The main view has this code:**

```
@model IEnumerable<MobileReports.Models.ReportViewModel> 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Display";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="chartContainer" style="float:left">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("Partial_ChartView");}
</div>
<div id="secondChartContainer" style="float:right">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("Partial_ChartView");}
</div>
```

The Model itself contains only a rendered chart and a few infos about it.

My problem is, I don't know if I am doing it right. The mainview has to know which charts are already displayed on the page, so that I dont display the same chart twice. In the initial load, I somehow have to tell the partialviews which charts are already being displayed on the page. How can I do that?

Also how do I keep multiple models on the main view?

**-edit-**

The controller action DisplayChart(Guid? id) is used inside the partialView from a javascript function:

```
function displayNextReport() {
    // try to find a report that is not displayed already
    var diff = $(availableReports).not(displayedCharts).get();

    if (diff.length > 0) {

        // remove old chart data
        if ($("#chart_container").highcharts() !== undefined) {
            $("#chart_container").highcharts().destroy();
        }

        // load the new report
        $("#chart_container").load('@Url.Action("DisplayChart", "Report")', { id: diff[0] });
    }
}
```

Note: This does not work right now. I need to pass an argument that tells the DisplayChart() method which chart to load next. For this, I need to know which charts are currently diplayed.

**My code is most likely very wrong and messed up. I think it is best to just describe what I want to achieve:
I want to have a View that displays multiple partial views of the same type. Each partial view has to know what the other partial view are currently displaying. Thats all I want to do..**

Comment: Which method is displaying the main view?

Comment: Display(Guid? id). The other method (DisplayChart) is displaying the partial views inside the main view

Comment: Where and how do you call `DisplayChart(Guid? id)`?

Comment: But are you using PrepareViewModel to prepare both a IEnumerable and a single ReportViewModel? Besides, why are you using one get for the main and one post for the partial? are you using ajax?

Comment: DisplayChart is called inside a JS function that the partialView has. This function has to check which charts are already displayed in all partial views together, choose which should be displayed next and then update the containing partial view with the new chart. It does so by calling DisplayChart(Guid) with the id of the next chart

Comment: @mitomed: Yes. PrepareViewModel checks the user rights, retrieves the charts this user can access and populates the model of the current partialview. Alas thats the theory, because it does not work I think. Do you have any idea how to do it correctly?

Comment: I think is worth updating the questin with the relevant js call, is that call just an "add new chart", is "show others" .... Anyway you can't use PrepareViewModel for creating the model of the main one as it uses an IEnumerable